# The value of $r$, with $r≤ b$, that minimizes the expression $(b/r)(n+2^r)$

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, algorithms

In the [book](https://sd.blackball.lv/library/Introduction_to_Algorithms_Third_Edition_(2009).pdf) "Introduction to Algorithms" by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, and Stein. in chapter 8 Lemma 8.4 is proved. (my question is after the proof of the lemma)

> Given n b-bit numbers and any positive integer $r≤b$, RADIX-SORT correctly sorts
> these numbers in $Θ((b/r)(n+2^r))$ time if the stable sort it uses takes $Θ(n+k)$
> time for inputs in the range $0$ to $k$.

Proof:

> For a value $r≤b$, we view each key as having $d=⌈b/r⌉$ digits of r bits
> each. Each digit is an integer in the range $0$ to $2^r-1$, so that we can use counting
> sort with $k = 2^r-1$. (For example, we can view a 32-bit word as having four 8-bit
> digits, so that $b = 32$, $r=8$, $k = 2^r-1 = 255$, and $d = b/r = 4$.) Each pass of
> counting sort takes time $Θ(n+k)=Θ(n+2^r)$ and there are $d$ passes, for a total
> running time of $Θ(d(n+2^r))= Θ((b/r)(n+2^r))$.

goes on... and in this part I will ask my question. In the quote I will mark the points of the questions that I will ask at the end

> For given values of $n$ and $b$, we wish to choose the value of $r$, with $r ≤ b$,
> that minimizes the expression $(b/r)(n+2^r)$. If $b < ⌊\lg n⌋$ **(question : what is the motivation that led to the choice of this inequality?)**, then for any value of $r \leq b$, we have that $(n+2^r)=Θ(n)$. Thus, choosing $r = b$ yields a running time of $(b/b)(n+2^r)=Θ(n)$, which is asymptotically optimal. If $b \geq ⌊\lg n⌋$,
> then choosing $r= ⌊\lg n⌋$ gives the best time to within a constant factor, which
> we can see as follows. Choosing $r = ⌊\lg n⌋$ nc yields a running time of $Θ(bn(lgn)$.
> As we increase $r$ above $⌊\lg n⌋$, the $2^r$ term in the numerator increases faster than
> the $r$ term in the denominator, and so increasing $r$ above $⌊\lg n⌋$ yields a running
> time of $Ω(bn/\lg n)$. If instead we were to decrease $r$ below $⌊\lg n⌋$, then the $b/r$
> term increases and the $n+2^r$ term remains at Θ(n).

Comment: Is $lgn$ supposed to be $\log n$ or are $l$ and $g$ supposed to be defined somewhere?

Comment: $lgn$ is supposed to be $log_2 n$

Comment: I've changed to it $\lg n$ for clarity for you.  If you don't like it, feel free to revert it.

Comment: This question is also posted on [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/159485/91753).